# How save a PDF file above public root and then retrieve it in PHP? (using fpdf)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm using fpdf to output a file to the server and then trigger an email. This works but there will be sensitive information in the pdf. How do I output the pdf to a folder above the public root? And then how do I retrieve that file again through a link?

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output('/applications/doc.pdf','F');
?>

<?php

$to = "oelbaga@newworldgroup.com";
$from = "Omar <oelbaga@newworldgroup.com>";
$subject = "Test Attachment Email";

$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "doc.pdf";

//$pdfdoc is PDF generated by FPDF
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdf));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
echo "mail send ... OK";
} else {
echo "mail send ... ERROR";
}


?>
```

Comment: I realized I can output to the directory above the webroot by simply writing out the real physical path.

Comment: This will not work if the php is running with a `chroot` configuration. (i.e. access to files that are not under the path of the scripts base directory)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, although there are probably major security holes with this.

Code to output the fpdf file above the public webroot:

```
$pdf->Output('...physical..path.../doc.pdf','F');
```

Retrieve that pdf and force a download:

```
$oefilename =  "doc.pdf";
$rootDir = realpath('/var/www/vhosts/lavaansmile.com/private/');
$fullPath = realpath($rootDir . '/' . $oefilename);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($fullPath)); 

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullPath));
@readfile($fullPath);
```

To get the physical path to your page you can use this:

```
 //get real path
$path = 'NameofYourPage.php';
echo realpath($path);
```